# Is is possible to use process output while process is running?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, boost-process

Boost.process allows the usage of Boost.asio in order to perform asynchronous read.

From what I understand, this is useful to read output while process is running without having to wait for the process to terminate.

But to access this output, is it necessary to wait for the process to terminate, or is it possible to access it while process is running, and how?

Actually my need is to access the beginning of a process output (to check that it started as expected) while while keeping it running.

To detail the context, I run a process which I want to keep until the end of the execution:

```
boost::asio::io_service ios;
std::vector<char> buf;

bp::child c("process_that_needs_to_keep_running", args, 
bp::std_out > boost::asio::buffer(buf), ios);

ios.run();
// I DON'T WANT WAIT FOR c TO TERMINATE
// but I want to check that buf contains some text that ensures me it started correctly
// the issue I have here is that I don't know how to read from buf, since its size and content might not be consistent
// is it possible to take a snapshot for instance?
check_started_correctly(buf);
```

Here the issue is that the producer creates output which I don't control, I just issues output.

Comment: If you couldn't read the output stream of a process before it terminated, you would have to *store* all of the output somewhere. Do you have a lot of RAM laying around?

Comment: @EOF so how can I access it while the process is running, for example for fetch some information at line 5, is it possible from a boots::asio::buffer?

Comment: @FlashMcQueen Assuming you are referring to File-based I/O on a *NIX operating system: As long as the I/O has been flushed to the OS and is not stuck in a userland buffer, it's fine. But that's a lot of ifs so a bit more context might be useful.

Comment: The whole *point* of unix pipes is that they allow multiple programs to form a concurrent pipeline for processing data. Originally, when Unix was invented on uniprocessor machines, this didn't give *parallelism*, but it meant that streaming processes could work on problems that would have required more memory to store some intermediate result than was available in any existing machine. The producer can run, fill a buffer (the pipe buffer) with data, suspend when the buffer is full. The consumer can then be scheduled and read until the buffer is empty. Rinse and repeat.

Comment: @Frank I tried to provide some code to detail more, hoping it will make my question clearer.

Comment: On a multiprocessor machine, the producer and consumer *can* run in parallel. The OS kernel will have to synchronize the processes' access to the pipe buffer, but as long as the I/O is a small part of the total execution time of the processes, you can have the processes execute in parallel.

Comment: @EOF does boost provide streams/buffers that enable consume it in a consistent way?

Comment: Have you considered consulting the [documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/doc/html/boost/process/async_pipe.html)?

Comment: @EOF I am currently on it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `bp::std_out > some_kind_of_buffer_or_future` you will usually get the result only at exit.

However, you can use an `async_pipe`:

```
bp::async_pipe pipe(io);

bp::child c( //
    "/bin/bash",
    std::vector<std::string>{
        "-c",
        "for a in {1..20}; do sleep 1; echo message $a; done",
    },                    //
    bp::std_out > pipe,   //
    bp::on_exit(on_exit), //
    io);
```

Now, you have to *explicitly* do the IO on that pipe:

```
boost::asio::streambuf sb;
async_read_until(                //
    pipe, sb, "message 5\n",     //
    [&](error_code ec, size_t) { //
        std::cout << "Got message 5 (" << ec.message() << ")" << std::endl;
    });
```

This works:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c9267cba5a039a22)**

```
#include <boost/process.hpp>
#include <boost/process/async.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace bp = boost::process;
using boost::system::error_code;

namespace /*file-static*/ {
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;
    static auto       now = std::chrono::steady_clock::now;
    static const auto t0  = now();

    static auto timestamp() {
        return std::to_string((now() - t0) / 1.s) + "s ";
    }
} // namespace

int main() {
    boost::asio::io_context io;
    bp::async_pipe pipe(io);

    auto on_exit = [](int code, std::error_code ec) {
        std::cout << timestamp() << "on_exit: " << ec.message() << " code "
                  << code << std::endl;
    };

    bp::child c( //
        "/bin/bash",
        std::vector<std::string>{
            "-c",
            "for a in {1..20}; do sleep 1; echo message $a; done",
        },                    //
        bp::std_out > pipe,   //
        bp::on_exit(on_exit), //
        io);

    boost::asio::streambuf sb;
    async_read_until(                //
        pipe, sb, "message 5\n",     //
        [&](error_code ec, size_t) { //
            std::cout << timestamp() << "Got message 5 (" << ec.message() << ")"
                      << std::endl;
        });

    io.run();
}
```

Prints

```
5.025400s Got message 5 (Success)
20.100547s on_exit: Success code 0
```

So you can respond to content you're looking for when it happens. Keep in mind OS and shells do stream buffering on pipes, but the default is line-buffering so, you can expect to receive input as soon as a newline is printed.

### Large Buffers?

The above kinda assumes that you can buffer the entire output up to the interesting message. What if that is gigabytes? As long as your pattern isn't gigabytes, you can keep reading until the criteria is matched.

Let's morph our example into an async grep that looks for the regex `class\s*\w+_heap` in all of the boost headers. Of course, this is many megabytes of data, but we use only a 10Kb buffer:

```
std::string text;
auto buf = boost::asio::dynamic_buffer(text, 10 * 1024); // max 10 kilobyte

size_t total_received =0;
boost::regex const re(R"(class\s*\w+_heap)");
```

Now we make a read loop that reads until match **or** when the buffer is full:

```
std::function<void()> wait_for_message;
wait_for_message = [&] {
    async_read_until(                         //
        pipe, buf, re,                        //
        [&](error_code ec, size_t received) { //
            std::cerr << '\x0d' << timestamp() << "Checking for message ("
                      << ec.message() << ", total " << total_received
                      << ")                ";

            if (received || ec != boost::asio::error::not_found) {
                total_received += received;
                buf.consume(received);

                boost::smatch m;
                if (regex_search(text, m, re)) {
                    std::cout << "\n" << timestamp()
                              << "Found: " << std::quoted(m.str()) << " at "
                              << (total_received - m.size()) << " bytes"
                              << std::endl;
                }
            } else {
                // discard 90% of buffer capacity
                auto discard =
                    std::min(buf.max_size() / 10 * 9, buf.size());
                total_received += discard;
                buf.consume(discard);
            }

            if (!ec | (ec == boost::asio::error::not_found))
                wait_for_message();
            else
                std::cout << "\n" << timestamp() << ec.message() << std::endl;
        });
};
```

Of course, this system might miss matches *if* the match exceeds 10% of the buffer size (because we only keep 10% of the previous buffer contents to allow for matches overlapping read boundaries).

Again, see it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c1982dc9bcac6af4)**

```
#include <boost/process.hpp>
#include <boost/process/async.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

namespace bp = boost::process;
using boost::system::error_code;

namespace /*file-static*/ {
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;
    static auto       now = std::chrono::steady_clock::now;
    static const auto t0  = now();

    static auto timestamp() {
        return std::to_string((now() - t0) / 1.s) + "s ";
    }
} // namespace

int main() {
    boost::asio::io_context io;
    bp::async_pipe pipe(io);

    auto on_exit = [](int code, std::error_code ec) {
        std::cout << timestamp() << "on_exit: " << ec.message() << " code "
                  << code << std::endl;
    };

    bp::child c( //
        "/usr/bin/find",
        std::vector<std::string>{"/usr/local/include/boost", "-name",
                                 "*.hpp", "-exec", "cat", "{}", "+"},
        bp::std_out > pipe,   //
        bp::on_exit(on_exit), //
        io);

    std::string text;
    auto buf = boost::asio::dynamic_buffer(text, 10 * 1024); // max 10 kilobyte

    size_t total_received =0;
    boost::regex const re(R"(class\s*\w+_heap)");

    std::function<void()> wait_for_message;
    wait_for_message = [&] {
        async_read_until(                         //
            pipe, buf, re,                        //
            [&](error_code ec, size_t received) { //
                std::cerr << '\x0d' << timestamp() << "Checking for message ("
                          << ec.message() << ", total " << total_received
                          << ")                ";

                if (received || ec != boost::asio::error::not_found) {
                    total_received += received;
                    buf.consume(received);

                    boost::smatch m;
                    if (regex_search(text, m, re)) {
                        std::cout << "\n" << timestamp()
                                  << "Found: " << std::quoted(m.str()) << " at "
                                  << (total_received - m.size()) << " bytes"
                                  << std::endl;
                    }
                } else {
                    // discard 90% of buffer capacity
                    auto discard =
                        std::min(buf.max_size() / 10 * 9, buf.size());
                    total_received += discard;
                    buf.consume(discard);
                }

                if (!ec | (ec == boost::asio::error::not_found))
                    wait_for_message();
                else
                    std::cout << "\n" << timestamp() << ec.message() << std::endl;
            });
    };

    wait_for_message();
    io.run();

    std::cout << timestamp() << " - Done, total_received: " << total_received << "\n";
}
```

Which prints

```
2.033324s Found: "class d_ary_heap" at 6747512 bytes
2.065290s Found: "class pairing_heap" at 6831390 bytes
2.071888s Found: "class binomial_heap" at 6860833 bytes
2.072715s Found: "class skew_heap" at 6895677 bytes
2.073348s Found: "class fibonacci_heap" at 6921559 bytes
34.729355s End of file
34.730515s on_exit: Success code 0
34.730593s  - Done, total_received: 154746011
```

Or live from my machine:

[image]